# javascript calculate 10% discount on sub total

Tags: javascript, php, discount, subtotal

How to implement calculating 10% discount base on sub total in js?.
Here is my code.

```
<!-- Sub Total -->
function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input').each(function (index) {
                                grandTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sub_total').val(grandTotal);
}
```

Comment: what my code would look like?

Comment: `grandTotal - (grandTotal*.1)`

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this:

```
function calculateGrandTotal() {
                            var grandTotal = 0;
                            $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input').each(function (index) {
                                grandTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
                            });
                            $('#sub_total').val(grandTotal);
                            $('#discount').val(calculateDiscount(grandTotal));
 } 
//separate function to calculate discount
function calculateDiscount(amt){
   if(!NaN(amt)){
      return amt*0.1;//10% disc
   }else return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will add to the line of code?...or i will have a new function?...Sorry im just new in JS

Comment: how do i call that to display in the field?

Comment: what if i want to have anothjer function for discount because i want to compute the sub total and the discount to have a grand total...

Comment: function calculateGrandTotal() {
       var subTotal = 0;
       $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input').each(function (index) {
        subTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
       });
       $('#sub_total').val(subTotal);
       $('#discount').val(subTotal*0.1);
      }

Comment: if its woking what's the problem?

Comment: yes..but how would i use the two,.sub total and the discount?...because i have a grand total field...can you visit this link http://chocolatehillsadventurepark.com/reservation.php

Comment: You need to call this function wherever there is a change in the inputs. So that the changes reflect in the Ui. Your website is full of ads! It's cumbersome to look into

Answer (score 0):

Use getElementbyID to obtain value of your subtotal field and apply the formula.